# evalf integration with multiple free constants

Tags: integration, maple

How to get numeric value of integration:

```
eq:=int(c*x^(4/5)*exp((1+x)^(1/7)),x=1..2)
```

I tried to do:

```
assume(c,real);
evalf(eq,5);
```

The output I am expecting is:

```
4.32052c
```

But it doesn't work (with output same as input).

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Maple cannot numerically compute the integral if there are undefined constants involved.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I modified the question. I can get the result 4.32052 without c. I expect the output to be with c. The result also shows for int(a*x^2, x = 1 .. 2) = 2.33333a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pull the symbolic coefficient outside the integral, so that the definite integral is then purely numeric and may evaluate to a float under `evalf`.

```
restart;

eq := int(c*x^(4/5)*exp((1+x)^(1/7)),x=1..2);

             /   (4/5)    /       (1/7)\            \
          int\c x      exp\(1 + x)     /, x = 1 .. 2/

expand(eq);

           /   / (4/5)    /       (1/7)\            \\
         c \int\x      exp\(1 + x)     /, x = 1 .. 2//

evalf(%);

                     4.320521355 c
```

Comment: Thanks acer for posting, I worked it out similar way yesterday. Cheers!